# Count column value in a data frame

Tags: python, dataframe

This is my data frame

```
           Date    Name     Attempt   Count
0  2015-01-02    Adam       Yes      
1  2015-01-29    Adam       Yes      
2  2015-02-02    David      No       
3  2015-03-02    David      Yes      
4  2015-03-02    Hardik     Yes       
5  2015-03-02    David      No
```

Now I need to count the number of attempts of a person month-wise. Want to count only if attempt value is 'yes' and insert the value in count column.

This is the expected output

```
           Date    Name     Attempt    Count
0  2015-01-02    Adam        Yes          2
1  2015-01-29    Adam        Yes          2
2  2015-02-02    David       No           0
3  2015-03-02    David       Yes          1
4  2015-03-02    Hardik      Yes          1 
5  2015-03-02    David       No           1
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert `Date` column to datetime type if not already, then assign a temporary column as month extracting the month value from the `Date` column.

Then filter out rows with `Yes` value for `Attempt` column, and group it by `month`, and `Name` columns, then call `size` to get count, finally call `to_frame` passing `count` as column name to create a dataframe out of it, and merge it with the dataframe with `left` merge passing the common keys for `on` parameter, then `fillna(0)`, drop month column, and convert count column as integer type.

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['month']=df['Date'].dt.month
(df.merge(df[df['Attempt'].eq('Yes')]
             .groupby(['month', 'Name'])
             .size()
             .to_frame('count'), 
        how='left', 
        on=['month', 'Name']
        ).fillna(0).drop(columns='month').astype({'count':int})
)
        Date    Name Attempt  count
0 2015-01-02    Adam     Yes      2
1 2015-01-29    Adam     Yes      2
2 2015-02-02   David      No      0
3 2015-03-02   David     Yes      1
4 2015-03-02  Hardik     Yes      1
5 2015-03-02   David      No      1
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to group the date and names on a month frequency and count how many attempts were "Yes". Adding a little temporary helper info as unique month:

```
df['year_x_month'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.year * x.month)
res = df[df["Attempt"].eq("Yes")]
                      .groupby(['year_x_month', 'Name'])['Attempt']
                      .count()
```

`res` looks something like this (with MultiIndex as ('year_x_month', 'Name')):

```
year_x_month  Name  
2015          Adam      2
6045          David     1
              Hardik    1
Name: Attempt, dtype: int64
```

Now assign the amount of attempts per person and per month using a map for the unique combinations of year/month and person name:

```
my_map = dict(zip(res.index, res.values))
df['Counts'] = pd.Series(zip(df['year_x_month'], df['Name'])).map(my_map))
del df['year_x_month']
```

Output:

```
        date    Name Attempt  Counts
0 2015-01-02    Adam     Yes     2.0
1 2015-01-29    Adam     Yes     2.0
2 2015-02-02   David      No     NaN
3 2015-03-02   David     Yes     1.0
4 2015-03-02  Hardik     Yes     1.0
5 2015-03-02   David      No     1.0
```

**NOTE: removed previously flawed implementation**

After seeing the nice answer by @ThePyGuy. I was interested on checking performance of both his and my suggestions (none "correcter" than the other I hope ;)) and found out his suggestion to take 4.53 ms and mine 3.97 ms. Note that these statistics are for this small data set. It might be performance will scale weirdly with dataframe size.